# How do I copy files and return which files were copied?

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

How do I recursively copy all files in the current dir to the `/filename dir` and make sure it returns which files have been copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd /path/to/source/directory # in your question it is the current directory 
cp -rv . /path/to/destination/directory # in your question it is named filename
```

- `cp` - copy files and directories
- `-rv` stands for two options of `cp`: recursive and verbose. The verbose option returns which files have been copied.
- The `.` character after `-rv` stands for the current directory.